# Finding a closed form for $\sum_{k=0}^{n}k^5$ using generating functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

***Question:***

> Find a closed form for $\sum_{k=0}^{n}k^5$ using generating functions.

---

$Solution.$

We define $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}k^5x^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$.

Therefore, $$\begin{array}{l}
a_{n} =\{1,1+32,1+32+243,1+32+243+1024,\dotsc \}\\
\\
b_{n} =\{1,32,243,1024,3125,7776,16807,32768,\dotsc \}\\
\\
c_{n} =\{1,31,211,781,2101,4651,9031,15961,\dotsc \}\\
\\
d_{n} =\{1,30,180,570,1320,2550,4380,6930,\dotsc \}\\
\\
e_{n} =\{1,29,150,390,750,1230,1830,2550,\dotsc \}\\
\\
f_{n} =\{1,28,121,240,360,480,600,720,\dotsc \}\\
\\
g_{n} =\{1,27,93,119,120,120,120,120,\dotsc \}\\
\\
h_{n} =\{1,26,66,26,1,0,0,0,\dotsc \}\\
\\
\Longrightarrow h_{n} =1+26x +66x^{2} +26x^{3} +x^{4}\\
\\
\Longrightarrow a_{n} =\frac{1+26x +66x^{2} +26x^{3} +x^{4}}{( 1-x)^{7}}\\
\\
\Longrightarrow f( x) =\frac{1+26x +66x^{2} +26x^{3} +x^{4}}{( 1-x)^{7}}\\
\\
=\frac{1}{( 1-x)^{7}} +\frac{26x}{( 1-x)^{7}} +\frac{66x^{2}}{( 1-x)^{7}} +\frac{26x^{3}}{( 1-x)^{7}} +\frac{x^{4}}{( 1-x)^{7}}\\
\\
\\
=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\binom{n+7-1}{7-1} x^{n} +26\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\binom{n+7-1}{7-1} x^{n+1} +66\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\binom{n+7-1}{7-1} x^{n+2}\\
+26\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\binom{n+7-1}{7-1} x^{n+3} +\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\binom{n+7-1}{7-1} x^{n+4}\\
\\
=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\binom{n+6}{6} x^{n} +26\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\binom{n+6}{6} x^{n+1} +66\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\binom{n+6}{6} x^{n+2}\\
+26\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\binom{n+6}{6} x^{n+3} +\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\binom{n+6}{6} x^{n+4}
\end{array}$$

By substitution,
$$ \begin{array}{l}
=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\binom{n+6}{6} x^{n} +26\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\binom{n-1+6}{6} x^{n} +66\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\binom{n-2+6}{6} x^{n}\\
+26\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\binom{n-3+6}{6} x^{n} +\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\binom{n-4+6}{6} x^{n}\\
\\
=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\binom{n+6}{6} x^{n} +26\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\binom{n+5}{6} x^{n} +66\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\binom{n+4}{6} x^{n}\\
+26\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\binom{n+3}{6} x^{n} +\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\binom{n+2}{6} x^{n}\\
\\
=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\left[\binom{n+6}{6} +26\binom{n+5}{6} +66\binom{n+4}{6} +26\binom{n+3}{6} +\binom{n+2}{6}\right] x^{n}\\
\\
\Longrightarrow a_{n} =\binom{n+6}{6} +26\binom{n+5}{6} +66\binom{n+4}{6} +26\binom{n+3}{6} +\binom{n+2}{6}
\end{array}$$

---

Now, I have checked over the Wolfram site, and it is incorrect. I don't know where I was wrong.

Comment: Your original series is divergent. What is $n$ in $f(x)=a_n x^n$? What is $b_n$, $c_n$ and so on?

Comment: What is the source of this problem?  Another question about sums of fifth powers appeared very recently.

Comment: @Gary you are right, I wrote this question really fast. My bad. Edited!

Comment: @lulu I really don't know.

Comment: It still does not make sense. The running index is $k$ in the first sum for $f$ but $n$ appears as the power of $x$. Also as I said the sum of $k^5$ up to infinity is a divergent sum. Isn't it $$
f(x) = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\left( {\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {k^5 } } \right)x^n } 
$$ what you want to write?

Comment: You really don't know what the source of your question is?

Comment: @Gary yes I have fixed that too. I really don't know what is going on with me today. I am really sorry!

Comment: You still have $
\sum\nolimits_{k = 0}^\infty  {k^5 } 
$ in two places, which is divergent.

Comment: It's called a "closed form", not "close form".

Comment: @Gary Right. Fixed that too...

Comment: Please edit your post to include the source of this question.  It is a duplicate of a recently asked question.

Comment: @lulu Can you provide the link that you are talking about?

Comment: If you can not provide the source, the question should be closed.

Comment: @lulu What do you mean by providing the source? I do not have it, it is a part of self-practice.

Comment: This [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4095795/) may prove useful.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel in the title I have said the in this question you must derive the formula from generating functions.

Comment: @lulu: OPs question in connection with his detailed reasoning looks sound to me.  What was the reason to vote for closing this post? Kind regards,

Comment: @MarkusScheuer  A very similar question had appeared minutes prior to this one (find $\sum_1^n k^5$ without using Faulhaber).  In these remote instruction days, we've had a lot of exam questions (and such) posted here.

Comment: @lulu: Ok, I see, thanks. Nevertheless this one differs clearly in quality by providing a derivation contrary to the other posts. But it's not that important for me ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems there's just an off-by-one error. Note that since
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{f(x)}&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^n k^5 x^n=0+x+32x^2+276 x^3+1\,300 x^4\cdots\\
&=\color{blue}{\frac{x+26x^2+66x^3+26x^4+x^5}{(1-x)^7}}
\end{align*}
the coefficients $a_n$ should be considered as
\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{c|rrrrrr}
n&0&1&2&3&4&\cdots\\
a_n&0&1&33&276&1\,300&\cdots\tag{1}
\end{array}
\end{align*}

> Taking $a_n$ as in (1) will result in
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^nk^5}&=\sum_{m=0}^4A(5,m)\binom{n+m+1}{6}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\binom{n+1}{6}+26\binom{n+2}{6}+66\binom{n+3}{6}}\\
> &\,\,\qquad\color{blue}{+26\binom{n+4}{6}+\binom{n+5}{6}}
> \end{align*}
> where $A(5,m): 1,26,66,26,1$ are *[Eulerian numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_number#Identities)* which provide nice connections with $k$-th powers of natural numbers.

All other calculations of OP are correct. The sequence
\begin{align*}
&\binom{n+6}{6} +26\binom{n+5}{6} +66\binom{n+4}{6} \\
&\qquad+26\binom{n+3}{6} +\binom{n+2}{6}\qquad\qquad (n\geq 0)
\end{align*}
starts with $1,33,276,1\,300, \ldots$ corresponding to OPs start of the calculation.

Comment: But it seems that $\sum_{k=0}^{n}k^5=a_{n-1}$, when $a_n$ is my answer. Right?

Comment: @sdfs: Yes, correct. If you substitute $n\to n+1$ in the blue marked result it gives your result (reverse order).

Comment: Why is it happening? I mean, why didn't I get that the sum equal to $a_n$?

Comment: @sdfs: You need to start with $a_n=\{0,1,1+32,\ldots\}$.

Comment: ohhhhhh you are right!!! that is what I missed! Thank you for your time!!!

Comment: @sdfs: You're welcome! :-)